# Cache won't clear

Tags: windows-7, dns, cache

I work as a web designer and I'm having an issue with Caching on my computer that happens when I visit a newly created domain before setting up any content, which I assume is when it caches. Then once I've installed WordPress, web pages etc. I get the following:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.yoursite.com’s server IP address could not be found.
>
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

**I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64bit for reference.**

The issue does eventually resolve on its own, but can upto 48 hours sometimes. All browsers are affected. The site works on my phone and through a proxy viewer like anonymouse.org

***I've taken all of the following steps, some multiple times in different orders without success:***

- Run Windows Network Diagnostics.
- Cleared the browser cache
- Deleted everything with CCleaner Cookies, Session Data, History etc.
- Used CMD line to flush and renew the DNS
- Rebooted my router (Got new IP)
- Rebooted my computer
- Logged into router, but no available options to clear cache*
- Cleaned the Registry & put the DHCP lease time to 10m (I'm desperate)

If it was the router cache, I'd assume all devices connected to it would be affected and the browser cache would be local to the one browser. *Please correct me if this is wrong.*

Therefore I guess it must be Windows caching it locally, but `ipconfig /flushdns ipconfig /renew` commands are the only system related caching I'm aware of, so I'm at a total loss.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching seems to be happening at the level of the router or is attached to my IP address, I found I can overcome the problem by either resetting the router if it's on a dynamic IP address or by using a VPN or Proxy.